# Putting a form in a component, problems with submitting form

Tags: visualforce-component, form

I have a component which I am trying to have a form submit. The form is handled by a managed controller in a managed package (which is a third party's). The component does not otherwise have code associated with it.

The component passes a bunch of attributes to the form.

Everything works -- it populates with data, an in-between AJAX call works.

However, the form does not actually submit. The submit button does nothing at all when it is in the component.

The form, otherwise identical on a different page, works fine.

Is there any general reason why this would be a problem? The one big difference between the resulting HTML code is that the IDs of the component-ized form are a lot longer. It seems like this might be breaking the binding between the form and the controller that is on the page... is there any work around for that.